# ORA-04098: trigger 'US_B375_SQL_S22.BI_ORDERS' is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle programming with SQL and I am having a bit of trouble with my lab assignment. In my lab assignment, in tasks:

> 3. Add order 12600 (order date: 09/06/2018, customer number: 311) to the database. Add two order lines to this order.
>
> On the first line, the part number is AX12, the number ordered is 5,
>   and the quoted price is $13.95. On the second line, the part number is
>   BA74, the number ordered is 3, and the quoted price is $4.50.

I am currently having trouble inserting the data into the table. I keep getting the error

> ORA-04098: trigger 'US_B375_SQL_S22.BI_ORDERS' is invalid and failed re-validation

whenever I try using the following insert into statement:

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS(ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DATE, CUSTOMER_NUMBER)
VALUES('12600', '06-Sep-2018', '311');
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? Or away from the error?

Comment: Hi @theghost please share with us your trigger 'US_B375_SQL_S22.BI_ORDERS' from your table ORDERS.

Comment: As the error says: there is a trigger in your database that is invalid. As long as this is the case, you cannot insert data into the `orders` table. You get more information with `select * from dba_errors where owner = 'US_B375_SQL_S22' and name = 'BI_ORDERS';` (provided you have the right to select from dba_errors). Well, I guess you are working on a database on a server and will simply have to tell some person responsable for it to fix the trigger :-)

Comment: If you do not know how to get the code of a trigger do this: `select * from all_SOURCE
WHERE TYPE = 'TRIGGER'
AND NAME = 'US_B375_SQL_S22.BI_ORDERS';` and tthen check all that is under the column TEXT.

Comment: On a sidenote: Don't insert dates as strings. This: `'06-Sep-2018'` is a string. Oracle must convert it into a date, which can easily fail, because it must guess its format. You could at least convert it to a date explicitely with `TO_DATE('06-Sep-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy')`, but the best way would be to use a date literal right away, which looks thus: `DATE '2018-09-06'`. (And don't insert numbers as string either. They must get converted, too. Hence just `311` instead of `'311'`. The same holds true for the order number, if it is a numeric column as its name suggests.)

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Thing is I never set up triggers. When using the oracle academy application express tool, we initially created all the tables  and entered all the data without  coding. So the professor basically just had us create the easy way. A solution I found was simply deleting the trigger lol. In a beginner SQL class , haven't learned that much about them yet. I am able to view the triggers by selecting the table from the object browser in application express. Looking at another table I have, this is whats seen in the trigger section "BI_CUSTOMER BEFORE EACH ROW INSERT ENABLED"